# Batch only display 2 characters past a decimal

Tags: batch-file

Does anyone know how to display only 2 characters past a decimal point.

Example:
19.123948493114 turns into 19.12

Can't use %variable:~5% because the number before the decimal changes so sometimes it will be 19 other times it will be 123451213.12345123

Both need to only display 2 characters past the decimal point

-= EDIT =-
Here is the current script I have.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CLS
FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%A IN ('fsutil fsinfo drives') DO SET "Drives=%%B"
FOR %%A IN (%Drives%) DO fsutil fsinfo statistics %%A |FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume." >nul || CALL:GetDriveInfo %%A
EXIT /B

:GetDriveInfo
SET "CurrentDrive=%~1"
SET "CurrentDrive=%CurrentDrive:\=%
FOR /F "tokens=7 delims= " %%A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %~1 ^|FINDSTR /C:"Total # of free bytes"') DO Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "%%A"
FOR /F "tokens=6 delims= " %%A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %~1 ^|FINDSTR /C:"Total # of bytes"') DO CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "%%A"
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell %CurrentDrive-TotalSpace% - %CurrentDrive-FreeSpace%') DO Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=%%A"

FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %%A IN ('powershell %CurrentDrive-UsedSpace% / %CurrentDrive-TotalSpace% * 100') DO (
    SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=%%A"
    SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=%%B"
    SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"
    SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!"
)

FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %%A IN ('powershell %CurrentDrive-FreeSpace% / %CurrentDrive-TotalSpace% * 100') DO (
    SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=%%A"
    SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=%%B"
    SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"
    SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!"
)

ECHO Drive Information For %CurrentDrive%
ECHO/ Used Space: %CurrentDrive-UsedSpace% (%CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent%%%)
ECHO/ Free Space: %CurrentDrive-FreeSpace% (%CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent%%%)
ECHO/ Total Space: %CurrentDrive-TotalSpace%
ECHO/
EXIT /B

:GetDriveInfo-Convert
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell %~2 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%%A"
FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %%A IN ("%CurrentDrive_Temp%") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%%A" & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%%B"
SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=%CurrentDrive_Temp2:~0,2%"

:: Rounds Up to get a more accurate number. Used to counter the lost bytes.
IF "%CurrentDrive_Temp2:~2,1%" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1"
IF "%CurrentDrive_Temp3%"=="100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00" & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1"
SET "%~1=%CurrentDrive_Temp1%.%CurrentDrive_Temp3%"
EXIT /B
```

The Issue?
one of the drives for no reason at all seems to want to not cut off.

My Results:

```
Drive Information For C:
 Used Space: 103.21 (86.5%)
 Free Space: 16.04 (13.4%)
 Total Space: 119.25

Drive Information For D:
 Used Space: 481.37 (57.8%)
 Free Space: 350.14 (42.1%)
 Total Space: 831.51

Drive Information For E:
 Used Space: 530.02 (99.7%)
 Free Space: 1.49 (0.2%)
 Total Space: 531.51

Drive Information For F:
 Used Space: 86.4 (43.2%)
 Free Space: 113.60 (56.8%)
 Total Space: 200.00

Drive Information For G:
 Used Space: 0.129999999999995 (0.0%)
 Free Space: 199.87 (99.9%)
 Total Space: 200.00

Drive Information For I:
 Used Space: 86.83 (9.3%)
 Free Space: 844.68 (90.6%)
 Total Space: 931.51

Drive Information For J:
 Used Space: 699.09 (75.0%)
 Free Space: 232.39 (24.9%)
 Total Space: 931.48

Drive Information For Z:
 Used Space: 11.06 (22.1%)
 Free Space: 38.94 (77.8%)
 Total Space: 50.00
```

My Shortened Script Debug File. I cut off the entire function for the C: drive and everything after the G: drive because that is the drive that is the problem, and i can't post more then 30k characters xD

```
D:\Desktop>SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS 

D:\Desktop>SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

D:\Desktop>CLS

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1*" %A IN ('fsutil fsinfo drives') DO SET "Drives=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "Drives=C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\ I:\ J:\ K:\ L:\ X:\ Y:\ Z:\ " 

D:\Desktop>FOR %A IN (C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\ I:\ J:\ K:\ L:\ X:\ Y:\ Z:\) DO fsutil fsinfo statistics %A   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo %A 

D:\Desktop>fsutil fsinfo statistics D:\   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo D:\ 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=D:\" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=D: 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=7 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree D:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of free bytes"') DO Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "375962980352" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 375962980352 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=350.142810821533" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("350.142810821533") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=350"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=142810821533" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=14" 

D:\Desktop>IF "2" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "14" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace=350.14" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=6 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree D:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of bytes"') DO CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "892827856896" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 892827856896 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=831.510738372803" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("831.510738372803") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=831"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=510738372803" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=51" 

D:\Desktop>IF "0" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "51" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace=831.51" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 831.51 - 350.14') DO Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=%A" 

D:\Desktop>Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=481.37" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 481.37 / 831.51 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=57"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=8910656516458"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 350.14 / 831.51 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=42"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=1089343483542"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>ECHO Drive Information For D: 
Drive Information For D:

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Used Space: 481.37 (57.8%) 
 Used Space: 481.37 (57.8%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Free Space: 350.14 (42.1%) 
 Free Space: 350.14 (42.1%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Total Space: 831.51 
 Total Space: 831.51

D:\Desktop>ECHO/


D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>fsutil fsinfo statistics E:\   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo E:\ 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=E:\" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=E: 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=7 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree E:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of free bytes"') DO Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "1599143936" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 1599143936 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=1.48931884765625" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("1.48931884765625") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=1"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=48931884765625" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=48" 

D:\Desktop>IF "9" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "49" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace=1.49" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=6 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree E:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of bytes"') DO CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "570704261120" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 570704261120 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=531.509761810303" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("531.509761810303") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=531"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=509761810303" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=50" 

D:\Desktop>IF "9" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "51" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace=531.51" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 531.51 - 1.49') DO Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=%A" 

D:\Desktop>Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=530.02" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 530.02 / 531.51 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=99"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=7196666102237"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 1.49 / 531.51 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=0"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=280333389776298"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>ECHO Drive Information For E: 
Drive Information For E:

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Used Space: 530.02 (99.7%) 
 Used Space: 530.02 (99.7%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Free Space: 1.49 (0.2%) 
 Free Space: 1.49 (0.2%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Total Space: 531.51 
 Total Space: 531.51

D:\Desktop>ECHO/


D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>fsutil fsinfo statistics F:\   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo F:\ 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=F:\" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=F: 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=7 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree F:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of free bytes"') DO Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "121982418944" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 121982418944 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=113.60498046875" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("113.60498046875") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=113"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=60498046875" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=60" 

D:\Desktop>IF "4" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "60" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace=113.60" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=6 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree F:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of bytes"') DO CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "214748360704" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 214748360704 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=199.999996185303" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("199.999996185303") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=199"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=999996185303" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=99" 

D:\Desktop>IF "9" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "100" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace=200.00" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 200.00 - 113.60') DO Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=%A" 

D:\Desktop>Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=86.4" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 86.4 / 200.00 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=43"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=2"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 113.60 / 200.00 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=56"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=8"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>ECHO Drive Information For F: 
Drive Information For F:

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Used Space: 86.4 (43.2%) 
 Used Space: 86.4 (43.2%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Free Space: 113.60 (56.8%) 
 Free Space: 113.60 (56.8%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Total Space: 200.00 
 Total Space: 200.00

D:\Desktop>ECHO/


D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>fsutil fsinfo statistics G:\   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo G:\ 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=G:\" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=G: 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=7 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree G:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of free bytes"') DO Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "214605746176" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 214605746176 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=199.867176055908" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("199.867176055908") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=199"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=867176055908" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=86" 

D:\Desktop>IF "7" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "87" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace=199.87" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=6 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree G:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of bytes"') DO CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "214748360704" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 214748360704 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=199.999996185303" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("199.999996185303") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=199"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=999996185303" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=99" 

D:\Desktop>IF "9" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "100" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace=200.00" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 200.00 - 199.87') DO Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=%A" 

D:\Desktop>Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=0.129999999999995" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 0.129999999999995 / 200.00 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=0"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=0649999999999975"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 199.87 / 200.00 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=99"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=935"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>ECHO Drive Information For G: 
Drive Information For G:

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Used Space: 0.129999999999995 (0.0%) 
 Used Space: 0.129999999999995 (0.0%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Free Space: 199.87 (99.9%) 
 Free Space: 199.87 (99.9%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Total Space: 200.00 
 Total Space: 200.00

D:\Desktop>ECHO/


D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>fsutil fsinfo statistics H:\   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo H:\ 

D:\Desktop>fsutil fsinfo statistics I:\   | FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume."   1>nul  || CALL:GetDriveInfo I:\ 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=I:\" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive=I: 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=7 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree I:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of free bytes"') DO Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>Call:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace" "906973425664" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 906973425664 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=844.684825897217" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("844.684825897217") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=844"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=684825897217" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=68" 

D:\Desktop>IF "4" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "68" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace=844.68" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=6 delims= " %A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree I:\ |FINDSTR /C:"Total # of bytes"') DO CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "%A" 

D:\Desktop>CALL:GetDriveInfo-Convert "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace" "1000202432512" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 1000202432512 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024') DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=%A" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp=931.51110458374" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ("931.51110458374") DO SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=%A"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=%B" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp1=931"   & SET "CurrentDrive_Temp2=51110458374" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=51" 

D:\Desktop>IF "1" GEQ "5" SET /A "CurrentDrive_Temp3+=1" 

D:\Desktop>IF "51" == "100" SET "CurrentDrive_Temp3=00"   & SET /A CurrentDrive_Temp1+=1" 

D:\Desktop>SET "CurrentDrive-TotalSpace=931.51" 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F %A IN ('powershell 931.51 - 844.68') DO Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=%A" 

D:\Desktop>Set "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace=86.83" 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 86.83 / 931.51 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1=9"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=32142435400586"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-UsedSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=." %A IN ('powershell 844.68 / 931.51 * 100') DO (
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=%A"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=%B"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>(
SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1=90"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=6785756459941"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2:~0,1!"  
 SET "CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent=!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent1!.!CurrentDrive-FreeSpace-Percent2!" 
) 

D:\Desktop>ECHO Drive Information For I: 
Drive Information For I:

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Used Space: 86.83 (9.3%) 
 Used Space: 86.83 (9.3%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Free Space: 844.68 (90.6%) 
 Free Space: 844.68 (90.6%)

D:\Desktop>ECHO/ Total Space: 931.51 
 Total Space: 931.51

D:\Desktop>ECHO/

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B 

D:\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . . 

D:\Desktop>EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer**

I was in the process of developing an answer that rounds the result properly when I saw your edited post.

If you are going to use PowerShell, you might as well really use it. I found this [Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx) that shows how to format a number.

The whole script would probably best be done with PowerShell, but I don't have any expertise with that language. So I threw together this hybrid script. There is probably a better way to do even the hybrid solution, but this works. It is much faster than your original because it reduces the number of PowerShell calls to one per drive.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do for %%C in (%%B) do (
  fsutil fsinfo statistics %%C |FINDSTR /I /C:"The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume." >nul || CALL:GetDriveInfo %%C
)
exit /b

:GetDriveInfo
set "free="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('fsutil volume diskfree %~1') do (
  if not defined free (set free=%%A) else (set total=%%A & goto :break)
)
:break
set "cmd=$used=%total%-%free%;$usedP=$used/%total%;$used=$used/1073741824;$freeP=%free%/%total%;$free=%free%/1073741824;$total=%total%/1073741824;"{0:N2}" -f $used;"{0:P1}" -f $usedP;"{0:N2}" -f $free;"{0:P1}" -f $freeP;"{0:N2}" -f $total"
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%N in ('echo !cmd!^|powershell -Command -') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set n!i!=%%N
)
set "drive=%~1"
echo Drive Information For %drive:\=%
echo Used Space: %n1% (%n2: =%)
echo Free Space: %n3% (%n4: =%)
echo Total Space: %n5%
exit /b
```

I don't like using FSUTIL because it requires admin rights, it is restricted to NTFS volumes, and your script is calling it twice per drive, plus one additional time.

I think it is simpler and better to use a single WMIC call instead. This solution is not restricted to NTFS drives.

*Edit - I simplified the powershell code by learning how to properly format an entire string with multiple variable references. I could do the same for the previous FSUTIL based solution*

I still post-process the PowerShell output to remove the space that PowerShell inserts before the % sign.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls
set "printCmd=;"Used Space: {0:N2} ({1:P1}^)`nFree Space: {2:N2} ({3:P1}^)`nTotal Space: {4:N2}" -f $used,$usedP,$free,$freeP,$total"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims= " %%A in ('wmic logicalDisk get deviceId^, freeSpace^, size') do if "%%C" neq "" (
  set "defineVarsCmd=$used=%%C-%%B;$usedP=$used/%%C;$used=$used/1073741824;$freeP=%%B/%%C;$free=%%B/1073741824;$total=%%C/1073741824"
  echo Drive Information For %%A
  for /f "delims=" %%S in ('echo !defineVarsCmd!!printCmd!^|powershell -Command -') do (
    set "str=%%S"
    echo !str: %%=%%!
  )
  echo(
)
```

I'm sure someone who knows PowerShell could easily strip out the batch portion from the above and give an even shorter pure PowerShell script.

**Original Answer**

*Note - This original answer truncates after the 2nd decimal digit. It does not do any rounding*

Break up the number into 2 parts, the whole number and the fractional number. "00" is appended to the fractional portion to make sure it has at least 2 digits. Then put the number back together, truncating the fractional portion to 2 digits in the process.

The following code expects a decimal number as the first and only parameter.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set num=%1
set part1=%num:.=&rem %
set "part2=%num:*.=%"
if "%part2%" neq "%num%" (set "part2=%part2%00") else set "part2=00"
set "num=%part1%.%part2:~0,2%
echo num=%num%
```

The tricky part is to get the whole number portion. I use variable expansion search and replace to inject a REM command into the SET statement.

If num =19.123, then `set part1=%num:.=&rem %` becomes `set part2=19&rem 123`

**Native batch method to round a decimal number to 1/100 precision**

I like your use of FOR /F to parse the number into the whole and fractional portion. But your original code has potential problems with the rounding logic.

I haven't diagnosed exactly why your one drive letter fails, but there is a problem in your code with a value like `1.09`. SET /A will interpret `09` as hexadecimal and will throw an error because 9 is not a valid hex digit. Your method also has problems if the whole number portion is missing before the `.`, though that should never happen in your situation.

I don't think either of those problems are causing your particular failure, but I thought I would provide a pure batch method that should reliably round any decimal number to 1/100 precision.

Again, the script expects a decimal number as the first and only parameter.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in ("0%~1") do (
  set "part1=%%A"
  set "part2=1%%B000"
)
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%part1%1") do (
  set /a "part1=%%N/10, roundup=%part2:~3,1%/5, part2=%part2:~0,3%+roundup, part1+=(part2/200)"
)
set "num=%part1%.%part2:~1,2%"
echo num=%num%
```

Finally, here is another version that takes the number of decimal digits to preserve as a 2nd parameter. It should always work as long as the input number is less than 200000000 and the requested number of decimal digits is less than or equal to 9.

```
@echo off
:roundDecimal  number  precision
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in ("0%~1") do (
  set "part1=%%A"
  set "part2=1%%B0000000000"
)
set /a len=%~2+1
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%part1%1") do (
  set /a "part1=%%N/10, roundup=!part2:~%len%,1!/5, part2=!part2:~0,%len%!+roundup"
  set /a "part1+=(!part2:~0,1!/2)"
)
if %~2 gtr 0 (set num=%part1%.!part2:~1,%~2!) else set num=%part1%
echo num=%num%
```

Comment: interesting idea, mind taking relook at my post, i sorta got the same thing figured out but am having an issue, it works perfectly for all except 1 drive.

Comment: @user1451070 - see my revised answer

Comment: Thanks for all the help really did a lot better for the overall effect than I did, I thought I had something great going :P Also would you mind explaining in more detail exactly how this line works o.0: set "cmd=$used=%total%-%free%;$usedP=$used/%total%;$used=$used/1073741824;$freeP=%free%/%total%;$free=%free%/1073741824;$total=%total%/1073741824;"{0:N2}" -f $used;"{0:P1}" -f $usedP;"{0:N2}" -f $free;"{0:P1}" -f $freeP;"{0:N2}" -f $total"

Comment: @user1451070 - I'm just defining a concatenated list of commands that gets piped as input to PowerShell. The commands are delimited by `;`. The first half of the "script" simply defines variables using math. The 2nd half uses number formatting as described in the link I provided in my answer. I've learned more about how PowerShell string formatting works and further simplified the WMIC solution.