# Round up the first 3 decimals in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I haven't been able to figure out how to roundup to 3 decimals.

It is very similar to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652402/batch-only-display-2-characters-past-a-decimal)

Decimals always vary, sometimes 5 and other times 15. But it must be rounded up to 3 decimals.

Using this to generate the file size:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell %FileSize% / 1048576') do (set SizeMB=%%a)
```

Is there a proper and simple way to round up the decimals?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can easily display the filesize in megabytes to 3 decimal places using PowerShell, however, it seems pointless to retrieve a files size in bytes using cmd.exe, then use PowerShell to modify the result. Can you please expand on your provided code, [by editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53978979/edit), in order to see if there's a more efficient way of performing the whole task.

Comment: `powershell -nop -c "'{0:n3}MB' -f (%filesize%/1MB)"`

Comment: @LotPings: thanks a lot. It's short and simple!

Comment: Alternatively, `For /F %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "[Math]::Round(%FilesSize%/1048576,3)"') Do Set "SizeMB=%%A"`; _but note my previous comment_.

Comment: Why didn't you tag this question as Poweshell?

Comment: @Squashman wasn't aware that it can be done on the same count size line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand, can maybe need:

1. Change `"delims="`  to `"tokens=1,2"`
2. Take the results from 1st for and put in next for split in 2 part
3. Take the 1st `%%i` into integer number variable
4. Take `%%j` and add 000 (prevent `"x,000"` some like `"x,   "`) by `000%_Size_:~0,3%`
5. Take last 3 character in substring to form the decimal value by `%_Sizedec:~3%"`
6. Concatenate `%%I` + last 3 by `%%i,%_Sizedec:~3%"`:

```bat
set FileSize=98888765
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell %FileSize% / 1048576') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in ('echo/%%a') do (

        set _Size_=%%j
        set _SizeDec=000%_Size_:~0,3%
        set "_SizeMB=%%i,%_SizeDec:~3%"

    )
)

echo/%_SizeMB%
```